# What is the maximum number can store in MS excel with 2 decimal places

Tags: excel

I tried to store `999,999,999,999,999.22` in Microsoft Excel. but its automatically rounded to `999,999,999,999,999.00`.

What is the maximum number can store in MS excel with 2 decimal places? 
How we store large numbers in excel files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the documentations, but I did a quick test on my Excel 2007 and those are the results:

[image]

It's pretty self-explanatory and to answer your second question, you can store the numbers as text by pre-pending the number with a single quote: `'` (e.g. Use `'999999999999999.22`). It's not ideal, but that works. You'll have to multiply it by 1 or add 0 if you use this value in a formula.

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your prompt answer. I tried formulas as you mention. Its working